# Placeholder text in a Win32 Edit control

Tags: c, winapi

I am using the Win32 API. I have this code that creates an edit control:

```
CreateWindowW(L"Edit", L"", WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD, 100, 100, 200, 20, hand, NULL, NULL, NULL);
```

[image]

How do I put placeholder text inside of this edit box?

Comment: EM_SETCUEBANNER

Comment: Your edit control's parent window is clearly a Delphi `TForm` (based on the caption text and icon in the corner), so why are you using `CreateWindowW()` directly instead of using a `TEdit` component? In VCL, `TEdit` has a [`TextHint`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Vcl.StdCtrls.TCustomEdit.TextHint) property.  In FMX, `TEdit` has a [`TextPrompt`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/FMX.Edit.TCustomEdit.TextPrompt) property. These both handle the kind of placeholder text you are looking for.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `SendMessage` with `EM_SETCUEBANNER`:

```
HWND editCtlHandle = CreateWindowW(L"Edit", L"", WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD | WS_BORDER, 100, 100, 200, 20, hWnd, NULL, hInstance, NULL);
WCHAR placeholderText[] = L"Enter here";
SendMessage(editCtlHandle, EM_SETCUEBANNER, FALSE, (LPARAM)placeholderText);
```

Or use `Edit_SetCueBannerText` macro:

```
Edit_SetCueBannerText(editCtlHandle, placeholderText);
```

The result will like this:

[image]